# Setting up a Git remote with a truncated history

Tags: git

I am in the midst of doing some non-standard, probably doomed, experiments on a git repository. The goal is to create a remote repository with a truncated history which can still share commits with an internal repository which has a full history.

I've had some success using a graft to connect the public history with the private history - when I push from my internal repository, only the post-graft contents are included.

So my main question is: what is the simplest way of taking a commit, eliminating its parent and writing a graft in place of the parent?

A more general question: is what I'm trying to do going to cause me pain in the long run, do you know if there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Chacon talks about something similar to what you're describing in a <strike>[recent Pro Git post](http://progit.org/2010/03/17/replace.html)</strike> ([updated location](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/17/replace.html)). He uses `git rebase --onto` to separate the history into two parts, later showing how to use `git replace` to restore the history later, should you want to do so. I've never done this myself, but it's explained in great detail in his post. Lots of diagrams too.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work and I've attempted that method and got lots of merge conflicts with it.

Comment: @ryber, I updated the link location, thanks to some help from the Wayback Machine, but I can't really speak to your merge conflicts.